# How NFC smart label work. Authenticity checks using the right NFC label and for the right product?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

There are some solutions in the market where NFC with RFID are used for Authenticity checks using the right NFC label and for the right product.

That is fine where any attempt made to open the label results in breakage of the RFID circuitry, rendering the tag non-readable. A non-readable tag makes the authenticity check unsuccessful.

> The problem is that I am unsure of how to detect whether a RFID sealed circuit has been broken using an Android app. In the event that we re-detect an NFC tag after breaking the seal, what kind of data do we get?

> In order to accomplisha Counterfeit Protection, physical-digital seals and tamper-proof NFC with RFID tag

[image: Counterfeit Protection, physical-digital seals and tamper-proof NFC and RFID tag]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

So the answer you want will be very specific to the make and model of the Tag, so impossible to answer in detail.

But as an example if you look at the [datasheet for a NXP 424 DNA](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NT4H2421Tx.pdf) Tag which has Anti Tamper features there is a Custom Command `F7h` to check the Status of the Tamper circuit if the Tag is still operating.

It also has a custom command to check a originality check that allows verification of the genuineness of the Tag.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I'll look into it further